# Where to find the issue report of Android Source Code?

Tags: android, git

We are trying to find the Android Source Code issue reports that are mentioned in their Git log messages.

Take the commit ​030b76f of platform_system_core for example, its commit log message contains "Fix userdebug build.Apparently this code I thought was unused is just unused for engbuilds...Bug: 17626262".

Here is the link to this commit.
https://github.com/android/platform_system_core/commit/030b76fc1d2884b8bafb2bdcd4d9947b351d627d

But we cannot find the corresponding issue report from the Android Issue Tracker system.
Here is the Android Issue Tracker system.
http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/list

So does anyone can let us know where to find the issue report for "Bug:17626262"
that was mentioned in the commit log message of commit "​030b76f" of platform_system_core of the Android Source Code?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is in the internal Google bug tracker. Non googlers don't have access to it

Answer (score 0):

An engineer from Google let me know that this is an issue number coming from an internal bug tracker. Unfortunately this means you have no way to access the report.

Comment: Many thanks for @Quanturium as well. I truly hope that I can accept more than one answers for a question here.